# How to set ResponseEntity to HTTP 404 for Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, http

Am using Java 1.7 and Spring 4 MVC to create a Rest Controller but need it to return an HTTP 404 ResponseEntity if my dao returns an empty result.

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    private final OrderDao dao;
    private HttpHeaders headers = null;

    @Autowired
    public OrderController(OrderDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{orderId}/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "APPLICATION/JSON")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getOrderDetails(@PathVariable("orderId") String orderId, 
                                                  @PathVariable("productId") String productId) {

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(dao.getOrderDetails(orderId,productId), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }   
}
```

How can I setup so that if dao.getOrderDetails(orderId,productId) is null that it should return an HTTP 404 for the client program accessing this Rest Call?

Tried this:

```
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = new ResponseEntity<Object>(dao.getOrderDetails(orderId,productId), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    if (response == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return response;
```

But Eclipse is saying that this the if clause is "dead code"...

Comment: You should check if the return value of `getOrderDetails` is `null` then and instantiate the `ResponseEntity` correctly based on that.

Comment: `result =  dao.getOrderDetails(orderId,productId);`  `if (result == null) return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);`

Comment: Why you are so scared to convert your response? You are using `@RestController` annotation which do that json conversion for your response automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is dead code because `response` variable never will be `null`. Try with this:

```
Object data = dao.getMlsPlayerSeasonStats(profileId,sportsTeamId);// I don´t know the DAO operation return type
if (data == null) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
return new ResponseEntity<Object>(data, headers, HttpStatus.OK);;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution that worked for me... Fixed it before your posting.